# Python MySQL, get special column names

Tags: python

I am using Python to fetch MySQL process.

The codes are shown below:

```
    import mysql.connector
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='192.168.95.9', user='root',
        passwd='qwe123', database='information_schema')
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    
    sql = "SELECT CONCAT('KILL ',id,';') FROM information_schema.processlist 
           WHERE `TIME`>100 AND `COMMAND` = 'Sleep' AND `DB` IN ('api','monitor', 'workflow');"
    
    cursor.execute(sql)
    cursor.fetchall()
```

The sql shown above can get results but in python, it returns nothing. When I get rid of the `where` condition, it returns values as expected. I also tried

```
sql = "SELECT CONCAT('KILL ',id,';') FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE \`TIME\`>100 AND \`COMMAND\` = 'Sleep' AND \`DB\` IN ('api','monitor', 'workflow');"
```

But it returns error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\`TIME\`>100 lim
```

How to address this issue?

Comment: So, you've demonstrated that error reporting works; if you produce an erroneous query, you get an error. The original query does not produce an error, so it's fine syntactically and all the columns appear to exist. That just leaves the `WHERE` clause not matching anything. Why are you sure that it *should* match anything?

Comment: @deceze because I execute the query in my MySQL client and it returns expected results. Then I COPY the exact query but it returns nothing.

Comment: Well, that table contains very dynamic information; are you sure those processes you expect to be there are there when you query them? What do you get when you leave off the `WHERE` clause; do you get data which should have matched that clause?

Comment: @deceze Yes it comprises dynamic info but when I check the mysql firstly, process X exists; Then I got empty in Python; Then I return tomysql, process X still exists and its `time` increases. There are hundreds of processes, although they are dynamic, result should not be empty.